# apache virtual host not opening when given subfolders

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have set up a virtual host in apache this morning and it works well for the root folder.

Settings for virtual hosts -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.abcworld.com
    ServerAlias dev.abcworld.com
    DocumentRoot C:\nem\wamp\www\dev\html

    <Directory C:\nem\wamp\www\dev\html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
</Directory> 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName prod.abcworld.com
    ServerAlias prod.abcworld.com
    DocumentRoot C:\nem\wamp\www\prod\html

    <Directory C:\nem\wamp\www\prod\html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
</Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Example : 
dev.abcworld.com   -    works well
prod.abcworld.com     -    works well

but when ever I click a link in dev.abcworld.com which is supposed to redirect to another page in the project like dev.abcworld.com/payments or dev.abcworld.com/somthing or dev.abcworld.com/anything it always says "The requested URL /apartments was not found on this server."

why does is works only on the root folder? how can i make this work for the whole project both in dev and prod?

Answer (score 0):

open your browser console and check to which path it is sending request.